# Excel: Display Array of Numbers from Range in single cell

Tags: excel

Is there a way to concatenate an nxm Range with numbers in one single cell?

For example:

```
1   2   3

4   5   6

->

{1 2 3; 4 5 6}
```

This is what Excel does when I select a range in the formula window and press F9. I am looking for a way to do this directly with a function.

Comment: WIthout VBA, practically no. Using worksheet formulas, this would only be doable in a very restricted number of cases, for example if nxm was <=15 and each value within the range was a single-digit integer.

Comment: how would i do it with vba?

Comment: How exactly do you want the result to display? Comma-separated?

Comment: yes, or with spaces for the columns and semicolons for the rows, like in the example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
Option Explicit
Function merge(rang As Range) As String
Dim r, c As Range
merge = "{"
    For Each r In rang.Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
            merge = merge & c.Value & " "
        Next c
        merge = merge & ";"
    Next r
    merge = Left(merge, Len(merge) - 1) & "}"
End Function
```

Then, you can then call the function merge from excel and use any range as the input. I dont think there is a standard function of excel that will do it.

Comment: I don't see why anyone down-voted it, especially without leaving a comment. Something like this is the way to go. A possible tweak to the code would be to have optional delimiter parameters which default to " " and ";"